# odata open type filter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

Trying to use OData filter in WebApi 2.

But it seems it`s not working over open type (dynamic properties).

Receiving error :

> Validating OData QueryNode of kind CollectionOpenPropertyAccess is not
>   supported by FilterQueryValidator.

Server return Array of objects that include Id and Properties , and in Properties i have property that contain array of string.. I want to make filter over this array.. I'm sure my request url is ok because it works with ordinary data. I think the problem is in open type .. I found this question is very similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427594/filter-by-datetime-with-odata-in-dictionary/33442032 , but doesn`t have answer ?

Using : Odata v4 and WebApi2

Example server result :

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Context@odata.type": "#Collection(String)",
    "Context": [
        "Context1", "Context2"
    ]
}
```

Example http request :

```
http://localhost/API/odata/GetItems(id=30045)?$count=true&$filter=Context%2Fany(c:+c+eq+%27Context1%27)&$format=json&$top=5
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by now, Open an issue to track

> https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/770